# Zoom feature in ASP.NET 4.0 Chart control

Tags: asp.net, charts

Does ASP.NET 4.0 Chart control includes zooming feature? I know and I read in most of the places that ASP.NET 3.5 doesn't have zooming feature. But is it included in 4.0? I couldn't find any official link stating that. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The zooming and scrolling feature is only for [Windows Form](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456632%28VS.100%29.aspx).